# Java starts reading null after half the number of cells

Tags: java, file-io

I was doing a project on a CLI spreadsheet program. I used this code to input from file :

```
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter filename (with path) - ");
    String fn=in.readLine();
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(fn);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

    String sen="";
    while(true)
    {
        String sn=br.readLine();
        if(sn==null)
            break;
        sen=sen+sn;
    }
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(sen,"|");
    String s[][][]=new String[(st.countTokens()/9)][9][3];
    int r_0=(st.countTokens()/9);
    int r,c;
    r=c=0;

    for(int i=0;i<st.countTokens();i++)
    {
        StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(st.nextToken(),"ɰ");
        s[r][c][0]=st1.nextToken();
        s[r][c][1]=st1.nextToken();
        s[r][c][2]=st1.nextToken();

        System.out.println(s[r][c][0]+"\t"+s[r][c][1]+"\t"+s[r][c][2]); // to be deleted
        c++;
        if(c==9)
        {
            r++;
            c=0;
        }
    }
```

The spreadsheet has by default 8 visible rows (9 in total). Till 5th row, 5th column (or till s[5][5][0/1/2]), the program correctly reads the values from the file. But after that it starts reading null values. I would like to know the reason for this abrupt departure from normal behavior. Does it have something to do with memory usage?
[Update - It's occurring after half the number of cells, not specifically [5,5,0]]

Sample input :

```
 ɰ     ɰ     |Aɰ     ɰ     |Bɰ     ɰ     |Cɰ     ɰ     |Dɰ     ɰ     |Eɰ     ɰ     |Fɰ     ɰ     |Gɰ     ɰ     |Hɰ     ɰ     |1ɰ     ɰ     |8ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |2ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |3ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |4ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |5ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |6ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     | ɰ     ɰ     |
```

Comment: 3D arrays are a horror story waiting to happen.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But it does input correctly till [5,5,0].

Comment: Examine the data carefully, and make sure it follows the format you're expecting.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Of course, it does. I created the file with the same program (with the help of a different file). The thing that is troubling me is the fact that it stops behaving correctly midway through.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your input that should read but doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried starting a debugger on that code and step through it to check what it does when? Also, it seems that you read line after line into the same string without adding a token to it so `lala\nfoo` becomes `lalafoo` is that intended?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Yes, that's intended. It should be just 1 line. But when it wasn't working, I thought maybe that's where the problem is. This is the link to the sample input : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byc5hi92akPMV3JEcDRaWmxmT1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the code inline please, the question should make sense to someone reading it when google has long been gone (or discontinued google docs)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer It's too long to be uploaded here.

Comment: Edit it in the question, of course.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer It's edited, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: Food for thought from the JavaDocs for `StringTokenizer` "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should exchange the for loop with

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
```

instead of the `for`-loop. You are not using the `i` anyway.

Also, `countTokens()` function changes its value during retrieving tokens (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens%28%29))